# Jsoup - extracting tag:namespace

Tags: java, android, jsoup

i'm having problems extracting some data from webpage using Jsoup.

Here is the code:

```
<fb:comments-count href="" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" class=" fb_comments_count_zero">
<span class="fb_comments_count">0</span></fb:comments-count>
```

And, i'm trying to extract that `0` in `fb_comments_count class`.

Comment: How are you trying to do it? Show your code!

Comment: When i try to extract fb|comments-count i'm not getting inner class at all, even if i parse whole webpage. I can never see that inner class

Answer (score 2):

Do you realy need the `fb:comments-count` tag for that? You can select `span.fb_comments_count` directly by using `doc.select("span.fb_comments_count").

However, if you need the outer tag:

```java
Document doc = ...

Element commentsCount = doc.select("fb|comments-count > span.fb_comments_count").first();

System.out.println(commentsCount.text());
```

This prints the value of the *first* matching tag. If you need *all* of them then use a loop instead.

Comment: I've already tried that, the problem is when i first get doc, and print it to console i can't see that span.fb_comments_count, and everything else is normal, for some reasons jsoup wont parse that.

Comment: What if you parse only the html from your question? Same issue? Btw. what version are you using?

Comment: I didn't know you could use ns|tag to find elements by tag in a namespace, good to know http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax